# DELETE OLD CHART in powerpoint presentation from VBA EXCEL MACRO

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I wolud like to delete several different old Charts in some PowerPoint presentation, all the items that I want to delete are called "Object n".

I have already tried some differents code but no one of those works. the Problem is that I cannot get the Name of the Shapes.

```
Set ppApp = GetObject(, "Powerpoint.Application")

Set ppPres = ppApp.ActivePresentation

Set PPSLIDE = ppPres.Slides

For Each PPShape In ppApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes

    If Left$(PPShape.Name, 6) = "Object" Then

        PPShape.Delete
    End If

Next PPShape
```

Comment: Are you assuming that the presentation is already open and that some slides are selected?  Or do you need to delete ALL such objects in the entire presentation?  Your code expects to work only on selected slides.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you need something like this:

```
Dim ppApp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim ppPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim ppSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim ppShape As PowerPoint.Shape

Set ppApp = GetObject(, "Powerpoint.Application")
Set ppPres = ppApp.ActivePresentation

For Each ppSlide In ppPres.Slides
    For Each ppShape In ppSlide.Shapes
        If Left$(ppShape.Name, 6) = "Object" Then

            ppShape.Delete

        End If
    Next ppShape
Next ppSlide
```

**EDIT**

I made this presentation:

[image: Original Presentation]

It contains three slides with these shapes:

- Slide 1 Oval 3
- Slide 1 Rectangle 4
- Slide 1 5-Point Star 5
- Slide 2 Object 1
- Slide 2 Object 2
- Slide 2 Table 3
- Slide 2 Isosceles Triangle 4
- Slide 3 Object 1
- Slide 3 Object 2
- Slide 3 Object 3
- Slide 3 Right Arrow 4

I had to use VBA to rename the charts. Some pasted as Microsoft Office Graphic Objects were named "Chart x", others pasted as pictures were named "Picture y".

I used this exact procedure in an Excel workbook (unchanged from what I posted yesterday):

```
Sub KillPowerPointCharts()
  Dim ppApp As PowerPoint.Application
  Dim ppPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
  Dim ppSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
  Dim ppShape As PowerPoint.Shape

  Set ppApp = GetObject(, "Powerpoint.Application")
  Set ppPres = ppApp.ActivePresentation

  For Each ppSlide In ppPres.Slides
    For Each ppShape In ppSlide.Shapes
      If Left$(ppShape.Name, 6) = "Object" Then

        ppShape.Delete

      End If
    Next ppShape
  Next ppSlide
End Sub
```

The Excel workbook has the following reference added (VB editor > Tools menu > References):
Microsoft PowerPoint 16.0 Object Library

The version number (16.0) does not matter. It should work in Office 16 (2016), 15 (2013), 14 (2010), 12 (2007), and even earlier. Just find PowerPoint in the list of references, and check it.

Alternatively, use "Late Binding", and change all the declared types from `PowerPoint.Something` to `Object`.

I ran the procedure above, and no errors were encountered. Some (not all) of the charts were removed. I ran the code a second time, and the remaining ones were deleted. This could be a timing issue between the two applications. Knowing it might be an issue, I made a small modification to the procedure to incorporate a loop:

```
Sub KillPowerPointCharts()
  Dim ppApp As PowerPoint.Application
  Dim ppPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
  Dim ppSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
  Dim ppShape As PowerPoint.Shape
  Dim i As Long

  Set ppApp = GetObject(, "Powerpoint.Application")
  Set ppPres = ppApp.ActivePresentation

  For i = 1 To 2
    For Each ppSlide In ppPres.Slides
      For Each ppShape In ppSlide.Shapes
        If Left$(ppShape.Name, 6) = "Object" Then

          ppShape.Delete

        End If
      Next ppShape
    Next ppSlide
  Next
End Sub
```

This procedure took out all of the charts.

Comment: The presentation is already opened and the code overwrite without delete old tables on the pp. In the line _For each PPShape In PPSLIDE.Shapes_ I get **Compile error: Method or data member not found** and I don't know what to do.

Comment: @carlitoes add a reference to the PowerPoint library

Comment: @carlitoes What changed between your last two comments?

Comment: I made some mistakes about plural i.e. shape**s** or slide**s**. Thank you for your support

Comment: Yeah, I do that all the time.